# why "f\adsad" gets matched by javascript regexp:^[a-zA-Z]+$

Tags: regex

I test this in the chrome console, and it returns true:

```
var regex =new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/);
regex.test("f\adsad");
```

when I test it online (https://regex101.com/), it returns false..

Comment: Because in regex101, you tested against `"f\\adsad"`

Comment: `console.log("f\adsad")`…

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` already constructs a RegExp object. Why wrap it in another `new RegExp`?

Comment: @melpomene it is my fault, thanks to point out..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The javascript parser will treat `\a` as a literal `a` meaning it passes the string `fadsad` to `regex.test()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, get it!